# Why Liked button changes back to Like button when comment is Liked

Tags: python, django, ajax

i am new in django, i am working on a website where users can post comment and also liked comment. I am using Ajax to avoid page reload when comment is liked. The issue i am facing, when a user like a comment, it display 'LIKED' from 'LIKE'. it worked perfectly using Ajax, but when i reload my browser the button changes from 'LIKED' to 'LIKE'. I am thinking this problem maybe in the views. How do i stop LIKED BUTTON from changing to LIKE BUTTON when i reload my browser?

Template: ajax_like_comment.html

```
<form action="{% url 'site:comment_like' %}" method="POST" id="user-comment{{ comment.id }}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% if comment.liked_comment %}
      <button type="submit" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment.id }}" class="like-comment">
      Liked</button>
      {% else %}
      <button type="submit" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment.id }}" class="like-comment">
       Like</button>    
      {% endif %}
    </form>
```

Template: home.html

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
<div class="row comment-row">
<div class="user-comment-text truncate card-meta dark-grey-text">
<a href="{% url 'site:profile-view' comment.user %}">
{{ comment.user.username }}</a> {{ comment.comment_post }}
</div>

<div id="user-comment">
{% include 'ajax_like_comment.html' %}
</div>
</div>
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def home_view(request):
    all_comments = Comments.objects.filter(
    Q(user=request.user, active=True)|
    Q(user__from_user__to_user=request.user, active=True)|
    Q(user__to_user__from_user=request.user, active=True)|
    Q(user__profile__friends__user=request.user, active=True))
posts = Comments.objects.filter(pk__in=all_comments)
for comment in posts:
    print(comment)
    print(comment.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists())
    if comment.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        comment.liked_comment = True
    else:
        comment.liked_comment = False

if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('ajax_like_comment.html', request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'form': html})
return render(request,'home.html')

@login_required
def comment_like_view(request):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comments, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    comment.liked_comment = False
    if comment.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        comment.likes.remove(request.user.profile)
        comment.liked_comment = False
    else:
        comment.likes.add(request.user.profile)
        comment.liked_comment = True

context = {'comment': comment}

if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('ajax_like_comment.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'form': html})
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '.like-comment', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var pk = $(this).attr('value');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{% url 'site:comment_like' %}",
    headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val() },
    data: {'id':pk},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      $('#user-comment'+pk).html(response['form'])
      console.log($('#user-comment'+pk).html(response['form']));
    },
    error: function(rs, e) {
      console.log(rs.resopnseText);
    },
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have updated value of like on your backend or data storage?

Comment: @Bibek...I don't understand what you mean. Value is stored in database, and when I print out the statement I get the right print. When I click on LIKE button it automatically changes to LIKED, which is correct. But after that, when I reload my browser, LIKED button changes back to LIKE button, that is the problem. Do you know what the cause might be?