# How to display comment in a particular post

Tags: python, django

how do i display comment to a particular post in Django. I have watched lots of tutorials and i can understand that comments can be displayed with ForeignKey to a Post using related_name and id passing throught url. I have been stucked up with this issue, I will be glad if someone here can help me with this, i want to display comments to each particular post without adding a related_name to Model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    poster_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)

class Comments (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
    commented_image = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) #i don't want a related_name
    comment_post = models.TextField()

def home_view(request):
    all_comments = Comments.objects.filter(user=request.user, active=True)
    posts = Comments.objects.filter(pk__in=all_comments)
context = {'posts': posts}
return render(request,'home.html', context)

#this displays all comments for all post, how do i assign comments to the particular post commented on
{% for comment in posts %}
<p>{{ comment.comment_post }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on the primary key of the `commented_image` (which is a `ForeignKey` to the `Post` model) with:

```
def comments_on_post(request, post_pk):
    all_comments = Comments.objects.filter(
        user=request.user,
        active=True,
        commented_image_id=post_pk
    )
    context = {'posts': all_comments }
    return render(request,'home.html', context)
```

Of course that means that in the URL you should encode the primary key of the `Post`. So the `urls.py` has an `urlpatterns` list with:

```
# app/urls.py

from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('comments/<int:post_pk>', views.comments_on_post)
]
```

so you can then trigger the view by visiting `comments/14` for example to obtain the comments for the `Post` with `pk=14` (given that exists of course).

Comment: @Willem..Yes I know this is right, is there no way I can display a comment to a post without adding post_pk to URL? I'm displaying comments in homepage, something like this: def home(request)....... rest of codes here

Comment: @MrHize: you can use cookies, POST parameters, ajax calls, but actually imho these all are more "ugly". Furthermore POST requests are supposed to have side-effects, and the browser anticipates on that, and using cookies will often only result in more trouble, since it will be a challenge to get "rid" of then after you make the request.

Comment: you can use a get parameter `host?post_id=<a number>` and in your codes to get it as `post_id = request.GET.get("post_id")` or if you do not want to use url at all you can create a ajax request that will return your comments

Comment: @Willem.. Okay thanks, I actually thought there should be a way on how to get the comment display on particular post without related_name or id in url. Seems I was mistaken.

Comment: @MrHize: well you can, for example with cookies, since these are passed through the request *header*. Furthermore you can also work with an AJAX request, that for example loads data as JSON objects, and then you let do JavaScript the rendering work.

Comment: @Willem... Okay I got it.

Comment: @Willem... Please can you help with this, I think this has to do with the views, not assigning the value of Like correctly. You can look at it, or maybe I'm wrong. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654337/why-liked-button-changes-back-to-like-button-when-comment-is-liked